# why pandas Index, Series and DataFrame with arrow backend are backed by chunkedarray

Tags: pandas, pyarrow, apache-arrow

according to https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/user_guide/pyarrow.html
A Series, Index, or the columns of a DataFrame can be directly backed by a `pyarrow.ChunkedArray`. I wonder why Series and Index are not backed by `pyarrow.Array`
and DataFrame by `pyarrow.Table`, which seems more natural data structures.

I don't see how a chunked array makes sense for Series and Index as it seems a too complex data structure. I did not find any documentation or source code comment explaining this choice.

Answer (score 2):

`ChunkedArray` being an ordered list of `Arrays`, allows compute kernels to run in parallel without:

- chunking before the kernels start running (chunking requires allocations and data movement)
- concatenating the `ChunkedArray` produced by the kernels into a big array (a big allocation and a lot of data movement)

Comment: Still not sure I got it. I understand the interest of `ChunkedArray` in arrow, still not as the only one data backend data structure in pandas. If you create a Series, you will have a single chunk, so no benefit if you want parallel computation that is not supported anyway by pandas. Also as `ChunkedArray`  only contains data of the same type, you must have one `ChunkedArray` per column for a DataFrame. Why don't we use a `Table` to represent a DataFrame as `Table` columns are `ChunkedArray` anyway.

Comment: `pyarrow.Table` can only contain arrow data types. If you wanted to have a DataFrame with arrow compatible types and arbitrary object (which pandas support), than you'd have a mix of arrow arrays and numpy array (of object). You couldn't represent this with a `pyarrow.Table`

Comment: This pandas issue core dev discussion shows to process of deciding between `Array` and `ChunkedArray` https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/35169#issuecomment-656075042

There is no obvious advantage for `Array` vs `ChunkedArray`. `ChunkedArray` even if more complex has probably been selected because it support zero-copy concatenation.